# Sweet Alert box i add 4 buttons onely one button is working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sweet Alert box I add 4 buttons only one button is working. The 4 buttons pointing to the same box and same div the problem is the first button when we click, the popup comes the second button popup not coming how to fix this issue?

**JS:**

```
document.querySelector('ul.examples li.input button').onclick = function(){
    swal({
        title: "An input!",
        text: 'Write something interesting:',
        type: 'input',
        showCancelButton: true,
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        animation: "slide-from-top",
        inputPlaceholder: "Write something",
    },
    function(inputValue){
        if (inputValue === false) return false;

        if (inputValue === "") {
            swal.showInputError("You need to write something!");
            return false;
        }

        swal("Nice!", 'You wrote: ' + inputValue, "success");

    });
};
```

**HTML:**

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css">

      </head>
      <body>

      <ul class="examples">
        <li class="input"> <div class="ui"> <button> 1 </button> </div> </li> <br> 
        <li class="input"> <div class="ui"> <button> 2 </button> </div> </li> <br> 
        <li class="input"> <div class="ui"> <button> 3 </button> </div> </li> <br> 
        <li class="input"> <div class="ui"> <button> 4 </button> </div> </li> <br> 
        </ul>
      </body>
    </html>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: `querySelector` selector the first element matching selector. Use `$('.examples .ui').click(function(e) { ... });` to bind `click` event on all `.ui` elements.

Comment: can u please rewrite the code

Comment: i dont understand the solution u told me

Comment: Sure. Check this [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/pmkqyq4e/). `$('.examples .ui')` will select all the `.ui` elements inside `.examples` from DOM. `click` will bind the event on each of the element by internally iterating over the collection of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use querySelectorAll.
Because it returns all element, so you should loop over the returned values, like follow

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('ul.examples li.input button');

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].onclick = function(){
 swal({
  title: "An input!",
  text: 'Write something interesting:',
  type: 'input',
  showCancelButton: true,
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  animation: "slide-from-top",
  inputPlaceholder: "Write something",
 },
 function(inputValue){
  if (inputValue === false) return false;

  if (inputValue === "") {
   swal.showInputError("You need to write something!");
   return false;
  }
    
  swal("Nice!", 'You wrote: ' + inputValue, "success");

 });
};
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css">




</head>

<body>
 
<ul class="examples">


 <li class="input"> <div class="ui"> <button> 1 </button> </div> </li> <br> 
 <li class="input"> <div class="ui"> <button> 2 </button> </div> </li> <br> 
 <li class="input"> <div class="ui"> <button> 3 </button> </div> </li> <br> 
 <li class="input"> <div class="ui"> <button> 4 </button> </div> </li> <br> 


 
</ul>



</body>
 
 
 

 
 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use querySelectAll please.

```js
 Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('ul.examples li.input button'),function(button){
       
        button.onclick = function(){
            swal({
                    title: "An input!",
                    text: 'Write something interesting:',
                    type: 'input',
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    closeOnConfirm: false,
                    animation: "slide-from-top",
                    inputPlaceholder: "Write something",
                },
                function(inputValue){
                    if (inputValue === false) return false;

                    if (inputValue === "") {
                        swal.showInputError("You need to write something!");
                        return false;
                    }

                    swal("Nice!", 'You wrote: ' + inputValue, "success");

                });
        }
    });
```

```html
<html>
<head>

 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css">




</head>

<body>
 
<ul class="examples">


 <li class="input"> <div class="ui"> <button> 1 </button> </div> </li> <br> 
 <li class="input"> <div class="ui"> <button> 2 </button> </div> </li> <br> 
 <li class="input"> <div class="ui"> <button> 3 </button> </div> </li> <br> 
 <li class="input"> <div class="ui"> <button> 4 </button> </div> </li> <br> 


 
</ul>



</body>
 
 
 

 
 
</html>
```

Comment: Is it working? Did you check by running snippet and clicking on buttons?

Comment: sorry,I copy your code that forget to modify,querySelectAll return a list of nodes,not unique one.